# Please explain Hotspot optimization refactor from Preconditions.java in guava code base?

Tags: java, jvm, guava, jvm-hotspot

I was going through Guava code base and [in `Preconditions` source there is some explanation](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v20.0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java#L1122) as quoted below:

> All recent hotspots (as of 2009) *really* like to have the natural
>   code
>
> ```
> if (guardExpression) {
>   throw new BadException(messageExpression);
> }
> ```
>
> refactored so that messageExpression is moved to a separate
>   String-returning method.
>
> ```
> if (guardExpression) {
>    throw new BadException(badMsg(...));
> }
> ```
>
> The alternative natural refactorings into void or Exception-returning
>   methods are much slower.  This is a big deal - we're talking factors
>   of 2-8 in microbenchmarks, not just 10-20%.  (This   is a hotspot
>   optimizer bug, which should be fixed, but that's a separate, big
>   project).
>
> The coding pattern above is heavily used in java.util, e.g. in
>   ArrayList.  There is a           [`RangeCheckMicroBenchmark`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/test/java/util/ArrayList/RangeCheckMicroBenchmark.java) in the JDK
>   that was used to test this.
>
> But the methods in this class want to throw different exceptions,
>   depending on the args, so it  appears that this pattern is not
>   directly applicable.  But we can use the ridiculous, devious   trick
>   of throwing an exception in the middle of the construction of another
>   exception.  Hotspot is fine with that.

For which jvm(s) it is applicable? Why it is slow, I cant understand? What it implies for me as developer? Is it still applicable for java8 jvms by oracle and openjdk? How to take advantage of this piece of information while writing code?

Comment: That's actually a cool think to read on and think about, though I cannot see your question here. Can you please ask it more clearly?

Comment: It would really help if you'd give *complete* examples, rather than ones using methods we have no idea about, such as `badMsg`. It may well be a matter of inlining, but we can't tell without more information. It's also not clear what you mean by "in this class" - in which class?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's an [excerpt from `Preconditions` source code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v20.0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java#L1122).

Comment: The question would still be better if you'd provide a complete example though. It doesn't need to be all of the Preconditions code, but enough so that we don't need to follow the link - questions should be self-contained if at all possible.

Comment: My suspicion is that when the string formatting code is included within the method, HotSpot won't inline it, which can make a huge difference.

Comment: Has anyone confirmed this recently?  The comment dates back to 2009 - maybe this optimization is no longer necessary

Comment: Thats what I need to know, they havent changed it, recent release also.Also what jvms are we talking about.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it states that `throw new BadException(badMsg(…));` is faster than `throw constructBadException(…);` where the instantiation of the new exception happens within `constructBadException`. It might be reasonable, because there will be an additional stack frame to parse and convert into a `StackTraceElement` in the latter case, but it will affect mostly *microbenchmarks only*, where the stack depth is usually low so an additional frame has an impact. For real-life applications with thousand stack frames, that one more has no impact. But that’s still only a guess…

Comment: @Holger What matters is the case when no exception gets thrown. Given how many times it gets used and how rarely exceptions typically occur, I wouldn't bother to measure the throwing case at all. Typically, there's no stacktrace and then only inlining makes sense to me.

Comment: @maaartinus: My conclusion would be the opposite. When only the non-throwing code path matters, all throwing code should be moved into a method on its own, making the relevant method shorter. This raises the chances that the code is below the inlining thresholds. That’s a code pattern, I’ve also seen in the JRE code when not looking at twenty years old code like that of `ArrayList`. To name one example, `Collectors` has a method `duplicateKeyException(…)` doing the entire exception construction rather than message only construction—added in Java 9.

Comment: @Holger that's interesting, I thought that `duplicateKeyException` is simply there to not repeat the code twice (since it's used only two times there). I also hope that this is not true anymore for recent hotspots, that would mean I might need to re-factor lots of our code potentially

Comment: @Eugene: of course, it is motivated by avoiding code duplication. But interestingly it does not follow the twenty year old `if(condition) throw new ExceptionType(constructMessage());` pattern shown in the question, but rather the `if(condition) throw constructException();` pattern, that the Guava comment claims to be “*much slower*”. Speaking of code patterns used in Java 9, also mind [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487188/please-explain-hotspot-optimization-refactor-from-preconditions-java-in-guava-co#comment81855010_47431685)…

Answer (score 0):

> For which jvm(s) it is applicable?

[HotSpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) - Oracle's JVM implementation

> Why it is slow, I cant understand?

It's an idiosyncrasy of the JVM's implementation. There's no particular reason (as far as the JLS/JVMS is concerned) why it should be slower, but as of the last time someone profiled it, it was. The `RangeCheckMicroBenchmark` class you found has more details and examples.

> What it implies for me as developer?

Nothing. Unless you're implementing a class like `Preconditions` - which has millions of usages that all need to be as close to zero-overhead as possible - you have no reason to worry about this detail. That's why it's a code comment, not a Javadoc comment.

> Is it still applicable for java8 jvms by oracle and openjdk?

Probably, yes. The comment doesn't link to a particular HotSpot bug, but you might be able to search for mentions of the benchmark code in the JDK mailing lists and find relevant bugs.

It's highly likely `Preconditions` would be updated if the JVM's behavior changed.

> How to take advantage of this piece of information while writing code?

There's really no need to do so. If you end up writing Guava 2.0 you'll (hopefully) be running your own benchmarks and will find bottlenecks worth fixing that way. Attempting to take advantage of micro-optimizations without rigorously benchmarking your own code is likely to do more harm than good.

Comment: Java 9 has an equivalent, `jdk.internal.util.Preconditions` and it does *not* follow the pattern of the twenty year old `ArrayList`  code; the exception construction is not inlined into the method doing the check. This functionality is exposed through the public API of [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#method.summary), obviously, using these methods is the best choice for an application programmers, once migrated to Java 9.